# Leaving the Singapore airport during airline transit without using Singapore tours

Tags: transit, international-travel, transit-visas, singapore, singapore-airlines

I am an Indian national traveling from the USA to India. I have a long layover in Singapore (12 + hours from 7 PM to 7 AM next morning).

I have a US visa and a passport so I can avail the Singapore tours at Changi. However, they do not have any tours late evening - post 8 PM.

So I was wondering if I could leave the airport by myself for a night?

Also are there any good spots near the airport that can be enjoyed/completed during that time?

Comment: Deep-ending on your age and degree of interest in WW2 activities in Asia you may find Changi museum worth a visit. In my case, as a NZer born 5 years after the end of WW2 but with a strong interest in related matters, Changi museum is something of a "shrine" and visiting there  was a marvellous / traumatic / awe inspiring / dreadful / must do / agh-wow! experience. My adrenaline levels and heartbeat probably took an hour or few to return to normal. Some may visit there and find it unremarkable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're on Singapore airlines, I would enquire about the stopover benefits from flying Singapore airlines.

This could be anywhere between: Hotel + Attractions for 1 night for $1 per person (possible couples only though). [Valid for Australia, possible others, stay for $1.](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/au/plan-travel/local-promotions/australia/singapore-stopover-holiday/) Or a simple one-night fee for the full package, usually at a very reduced price.

I would definitely look up Singapore Airlines benefits for stopovers in Singapore, they are called "Singapore Stopover Holidays":

https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/plan-travel/packages/singapore-stopover-holiday/

**A quick alternative:** Request a $20 credit for use in/around Changi airport at no cost.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, [you can leave airport by yourself for up to 96 hours](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/new_delhi/visa_information/overview.html). See the "Travellers who are nationals of India" at the bottom, as there are some additional requirements if your  US visa is a single-entry visa.

There is nothing near the airport, but taxi from airport to Marina Bay Sands and downtown area takes about 20-25 minutes. MRT to downtown would take about 50 minutes. The Merlion area would be lit and lively and worth a visit. Chinatown is also about 30 minute walk from there.

Comment: Just note that on the way back you would have to take a taxi, as trains only start running around 5.30 in the morning, which might be too late to catch the flight

Comment: That's a somewhat harsh definition of "nothing": for example, Changi Village, Changi City Point shopping mall and East Coast Park (great seafood) are all within easy striking distance.  But with 12 hours the OP does have plenty of time to explore.

Comment: @jpatokal there is much more to see inside Changi airport than right outside it.